# VueJs 2: How to use one component function in another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 Components and need to use a function with prop from component A in component B. The function just hides/shows HTML Element. However, it doesn't work as it should.

My settings Component:

```
Vue.component('settings', {
    props: {
        settingsContainer: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
        <button @click="toggleOverlay">Settings</button>
    </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        toggleOverlay: function() {
            if (this.settingsContainer === 'block') {
                this.settingsContainer = 'none';
            }else if (this.settingsContainer === 'none') {
                this.settingsContainer = 'block';
            }
            console.log(this.settingsContainer);
            return this.settingsContainer;
        }
    }
});
```

The component where I use it:

```
Vue.component('sample-comp', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <settings
            :settings-container="displaySettings"
        ></settings>
        <div :style="{ display: displaySettings }">
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            displaySettings: 'block' //toggleOverlay should change its value
        };
    }
});
```

Main App:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12" defer></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next" defer></script> -->
    <script src="test-settings-bt.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="app">
      <sample-comp></sample-comp>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I see in console that toggleOverlay changes the value but it does not affect my style (does not change displaySettings value).

[image]

Comment: Use custom events i.e., emit event `this.$emit('css', 'block');` from settings and listen to it in sample-comp

Comment: Do not try and mutate the `settingsContainer` prop value from within your `settings` component. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using either an event or the Vuex Store to pass the settings value (Use the vuex Store only if this is a part of a bigger more complicated Application and the settings have other influences).

It is better practice to have a well defined API to a component and letting the component itself handle it's appearance instead of altering Component X's appearance directly in Component Y.

Additionally as Phil pointed out in the comments, you should never alter props. They should be handled as read only.

Here is what you could do:

1. Emit an event in your `settings` component when the display should be updated. Either have two events, one for showing the overlay, the other for hiding it or emit only one event with a boolean payload.
2. Listen to the event / events on the `sample-comp` and alter your css attributes accordingly.

Kind Regards.